# WOL over shared IP

Tags: networking, internet, wake-on-lan

I have network.

In this network there are 3 PCs.

All of them share one ip: atm it's 79.186.142.243

Every PC has its own uniqe local IP (probably network card IP).

IP of PC that I want to Wake on LAN is 192.168.1.103 (local IP)

**How to wake it up over the Internet?**

Image below shows ping status for shared IP: online - as Im writing this question from other PC :P) and offline - its local IP and its OFFLINE (but responds) - becaouse this PC is shuted down. Yet I cant turn it on from Internet, 'coz its just local IP.

When trying to wake public IP (giving MAC, IP and leaving Netbios Name and Group blank) nothing happens.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

WOL is using OSI level 2 (ethernet) to send the "magic" wake up packets. IP (OSI level 3) is not used. In order to wake up a PC in your LAN over the Internet you would need a router which would allow you to log in from the external interface and send the packet to the local LAN. Many popular routers have this feature.

Here's the instruction how to implement remote WOL using [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/WOL#Remote_Wake_On_LAN_via_Port_Forwarding) - just to give you the sense of what's involved.

Comment: Like this: http://i48.tinypic.com/j96aza.png ? This is my router, yet this seems not to work

Comment: The page you have linked is just a "virtual server" (aka port forwarding) setup page. Port forwarding alone is not enough.

Comment: I cant add ARP in my router HTML backend, telneting to it gives no respond...